# Vue. Динамическая привязка props кодом

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Есть код:

На странице:

```
<component :is="currentTabComponent" v-bind="currentProperties"></component>
```

И в app.js:

```
computed: {
    currentTabComponent: function () {
        return this.presentComponent;
    },
    currentProperties: function() {
        if (this.currentTabComponent == 'count-down') {
          var presentTime = new Date(Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000);
          return { date: presentTime }
        }
        if (this.currentTabComponent == 'introduction') {
            return { course_image: "asset('images/courses/169ed27b759041a0106b9468362f4777.jpeg')" }
        }
        if (this.currentTabComponent == 'exam-question') {
            return { question: '@json($question)' }
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу сделать аналог SPA в пределах одной страницы.
До этого были такие props: `:course_image = "asset('images/courses/169ed27b759041a0106b9468362f4777.jpeg'` и `:question: '@json($question)'`.

Как сделать привязку, чтобы все отрабатывало и правильно передавалось в компоненты?

Answer (score 0):

Необычно передан пропс - попробуйте так:

```
<component :is="currentTabComponent" :currentProperties="currentProperties"></component>
```

Comment: Так count-down даже перестал отрабатывать.

Comment: Значит есть еще что то, выложите в песочницу - будет легче понять что не так

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Точно, можно и так) Просто необычно - никогда так не делал, спасибо что просветили

Comment: Дело всё в том, что пропс тут не нужен. `is` может принимать зарегистрированный компонент, либо объект с настройками. Просто автор не приводит код дочерних компонентов, что там происходит мы сказать не можем.